# Copying row to another google sheet by ID - NOT WORKING

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to copy rows with the word "lead" from the 8th column to another spreadsheet with different ID and I am not getting any results at all. This is what I was able to do so far. I can not find the error of the code. Can you guys help me find it.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with lead is col 8 or H
  // target sheet Id is 1nMpOJrq79UZPI3T9ykc415pAHIODg2he5xqi-DY6Wt0
  // sheet name of target Id is Sheet1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nMpOJrq79UZPI3T9ykc415pAHIODg2he5xqi-DY6Wt0");
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "List" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "lead") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

  }
}
```

Comment: The code works for me, wondering if your script is authorized to access the spreadsheet?

Comment: Same here. Check execution transcript for useful info. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#execution_transcript

Comment: its giving me this error "Execution failed: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. "

Comment: its giving me this error "Execution failed: Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. (line 14, file "moving")" Line 14 is "s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);"

Answer (score 1):

Use range.setValues() instead of copyTo. 
Note that the format is not copied, only the values. 
I changed it that the dimensions of the range match that of the target range.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with lead is col 8 or H
  // target sheet Id is 1nMpOJrq79UZPI3T9ykc415pAHIODg2he5xqi-DY6Wt0
  // sheet name of target Id is Sheet1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nMpOJrq79UZPI3T9ykc415pAHIODg2he5xqi-DY6Wt0");
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "List" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "lead") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    target.setValues(s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues());
  }
}
```